# Error margin for a value in an if statement in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, error-handling, margins

I have a simple for loop :

```
for n=0:0.001:100
  if x<100
    do something
  end
end
```

However, due to the complexity of the code, the final value of x is around 100.345, hence the loop breaks.

I want to apply an error margin where `if x<100 ± 0.4` so that the statement is true and the loop restarts.

How is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the logical and (`&&`) operator to make a range. The conditional code is executed only if both statements are true.

```
e = 0.4;    
v = 100;
if x<v+e && x>v-e
    do something
end
```

You can set `n=0` in the conditional code to restart the loop if you like.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to check if two floating point numbers are within some tolerance of each other is to compute the absolute difference, then compare that to the tolerance. In your case it would look like this:

```
expected = 100;
tolerance = 0.4;
if abs(x - expected) < tolerance
    % do something
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that nobody mentioned this, but if you want to add an error margin you only need to do it in one direction.

This is because you only check whether x is smaller than the comparision value. Therefore you can simply do this:

```
for n=0:0.001:100
  if x<100+0.4
    % do something
  end
end
```

Of course you can also just use `x<100.4`